# Too many simultaneous requests with NodeJS+request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, promise, request-promise

I have NodeJS project with a BIG array (about 9000 elements) containing URLs. Those URLs are going to be requested using the `request-promise` package. However, 9000 concurrent GET requests to the same website from the same client is neither liked by the server or the client, so I want to spread them out over time. I have looked around a bit and found `Promise.map` together with the `{concurrency: int}` option [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html), which sounded like it would do what I want. But I cannot get it to work. My code looks like this:

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var URLarray = []; //This contains 9000 URLs

function getWebsite(url) {
  rp(url)
  .then(html => { /* Do some stuff */ })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
}

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/some-database', function (err, client) {
  Promise.map(URLArray, (url) => {
    db.collection("some-collection").findOne({URL: url}, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      
      getWebsite(url, (result) => {
        if(result != null) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
      
    }, {concurrency: 1});
});
```

I think I probably misunderstand how to deal with promises. In this scenario I would have thought that, with the concurrency option set to 1, each URL in the array would in turn be used in the database search and then passed as a parameter to `getWebsite`, whose result would be displayed in its callback function. THEN the next element in the array would be processed.

What actually happens is that a few (maybe 10) of the URLs are fetch correctly, then the server starts to respond sporadically with 500 internal server error. After a few seconds, my computer freezes and then restarts (which I guess is due to some kind of panic?).

How can I attack this problem?

Comment: 9000 requests? That's too many. I'd take a step back and consider if there's any more suitable approach - such as setting up an API on the other server that can respond with multiple batches of data at once.

Comment: Yes, its ugly, but it's sort of a one time web scrape and I have no problem that this could take a whole day to complete if I can manage to spread it out over time. But, as you say, there are probably other better approaches that doesn't require all 9000 requests to be sent in one run.

Comment: Ok, that's reasonable. Are tons of parallel calls of `findOne` a problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what causes my computer to act the way it does. From what I can tell, the `rp` promise in `getWebsite` is what is producing the error messages. The database is local, so parallel `findOne` calls _shouldn't_ be the bottleneck, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is really about concurrency, you can divide the work into chunks and chain the chunks.

Let's start with a function that does a mongo lookup and a get....

```
// answer a promise that resolves to data from mongo and a get from the web
// for a given a url, return { mongoResult, webResult }
// (assuming this is what OP wants. the OP appears to discard the mongo result)
//
function lookupAndGet(url) {
  // use the promise-returning variant of findOne
  let result = {}
  return db.collection("some-collection").findOne({URL: url}).then(mongoData => {
    result.mongoData = mongoData
    return rp(url) 
  }).then(webData => {
    result.webData = webData
    return result
  })
}
```

[lodash](https://lodash.com) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) both offer a chunk method that breaks an array into an array of smaller. Write your own or use theirs.

```
const _ = require('lodash')
let chunks = _.chunk(URLArray, 5)  // say 5 is a reasonable concurrency
```

Here's the point of the answer, make *a chain of chunks* so you only perform the smaller size concurrently...

```
let chain = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
  const chunkPromise = Promise.all(chunk.map(url => lookupAndGet(url)))
  return acc.then(chunkPromise)
}, Promise.resolve())
```

Now execute the chain. The chunk promises will return chunk-sized arrays of results, so your reduced result will be an array of arrays.  Fortunately, lodash and underscore both have a method to "flatten" the nested array.

```
// turn [ url, url, ...] into [ { mongoResult, webResult }, { mongoResult, webResult }, ...]
// running only 5 requests at a time
chain.then(result => {
  console.log(_.flatten(result))
})
```

Comment: Or use [Bluebird's Promise.map()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with `concurrency` option. It's slightly more sophisticated than chunking in that it works on a "one-in-one-out" basis, in which the number of in-flight requests (or whatever) is maintained at a constant level (until the final few).